# .tmux.conf not being read?

Tags: mac, tmux

Trying to use tmux installed via Homebrew on a Mac.

I have the following inside ~/.tmux.conf:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Before I run tmux, in the regular Terminal.app, TERM is `xterm-256color`. After I run tmux, inside tmux, TERM is `xterm`. But is it supposed to say `screen-256color`? Is tmux reading my file correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Check your shell startup scripts. My bet would be that TERM is being overwritten there. tmux would set it before starting your shell, but it has no way to prevent your shell from resetting it.

Try running `tmux new-session 'bash --norc'` (or disable startup scripts in whatever shell you're using) and see whether TERM is set to `screen-256color`. If it is, that would confirm that TERM is overwritten by one of your startup scripts.